# String Conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need little help in javascript. I am using watson speech to text. User sometime use double or triple while giving phone number. How can I replace double or triple word with next number in a text. Please advice

```
let text = "my phone number is double 8 double 0 476 double 5";
```

Regards
Creedy

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service and we expect you to have done your research and come up with some attempts on your own to solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps a witful regex

Comment: You tried.. nothing? Stackoverflow is not a homework site, you show us what you've tried and we check what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for that and `String.replace()` method like this:

```
text = text.replace(/double (\d)/g, '$1$1').replace(/triple (\d)/g, '$1$1$1');
```

after that you example text value would be:

```
"my phone number is 88 00 476 55"
```

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) Takes first argument as [`regex`](https://regular-expressions.mobi/index.html?wlr=1) and second argument as what to be replaced from string if found in first argument.

So 
`/double (\d)/g` in regex means letters `double` followed by `digits (\d)` then replace it with the first matching group `$1` which in our case is pattern in brackets ie. `(\d)` which means digit. so replace it with `$1$1` means replace `double followed by Thedigit` by Two Times `TheDigit`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has Regular Expressions built in. 
You can use those patterns to find the "double 0-9" terms and replace them.
f.e.:

```js
let text = "my phone number is double 8 double 0 476 double 5";

text = text.replace(/double (\d)/g, '$1$1').replace(/triple (\d)/g, '$1$1$1');

$('#result').html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

(jQuery is only inserted to show the result)

You can find out **much** more about RegExp's here: [Mozillas Documentation: RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thanks ... I will look into it ... how can I do it without regex ? just for learning purpose ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you expect this:

```
text.replace(/double (\d)/g, '$1$1')
    .replace(/triple (\d)/g, '$1$1$1')
    .replace(/(\d+)( +)/g, '$1');
```

This snippet outputs "my phone number is 880047655". For more information about `$1`, you can see [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

Here is no-regex version just to get you idea. I am replacing double/triple words with next value.

```
let text = "my phone number is triple 8 double 0 476 double 5";
copy = text  = text.split(" ");
$.each(text, function(index, value) {
    if(value == 'double')
    copy[index] = parseInt(text[index+1]);
    if(value == 'triple')
    copy[index] = parseInt(text[index+1])+''+parseInt(text[index+1]);
}); 
console.log(copy);
```